# Differentiate syntax coloration of Python Strings vs. Docstrings in Textmate?

Tags: python, regex, string, syntax-highlighting, textmate

Love TextMate, love Python, *blah, blah, blah*..

But.. i *hate* that "Docstrings", aka multiline-comments / Sphinx's lovechild - are colored syntactically - in the same manner as normal "Strings", in my aforementioned *editor of choice*.  Here is an example of the two types in their overly matchy-matchy outfits...

[image: VISUAL AMBIGUITY lurking in python stringtypes in textmate]

Can this slight inconvenience be *regexed-away* - so as to differentiate the two more easily, visually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at lines 560-1064 of the language part of the Python bundle, you'll find the definitions for strings. Simply, you'd find the patterns for the triple-quote strings and add another component to the capture names. Then all you need to do is add that capture name to your current style and then triple-quote strings should be colored differently.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to code to your theme file to make doc strings appear different from regular strings.

```
    {   name = 'Pyton: Docstring';
        scope = 'string.quoted.double.block.python';
        settings = {
            foreground = '#A7C3CC’; //change color to your preference
            fontstyle = '';
        };
    },
```

If you need the XML version this is it:

```
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Python: docstring</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>string.quoted.double.block.python</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>fontStyle</key>
        <string/>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <!-- change color to your preference -->
        <string>#A7C3CC</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```